# Netgear GS608v2 switch + 802.1x

Tags: ieee-802.1x

Does anyone know what the difference is between GS608**v2** versus GS608**v3**?
I started noticing that machines connected to GS608v2 were not getting full network access (no internal connection) when 802.1x was introduced in our company, but machines connected to the GS608v3 (and v4) switches were working fine. Whats different in v3 vs v2? I cannot find any documentation on GS608v2.

I appreciate any feedback. Thank you in advance.

Comment: For a product to be on-topic here, the manufacturer must offer optional paid support, but, unfortunately, your switch manufacturer does not offer that for your switches. In any case, the switches are unmanaged, so they are not authenticating 802.1X, which is how the protocol was designed, so you are not using the protocol correctly, and it is no wonder that you have bad results.

Answer (score 1):

The GS608 are unmanaged switches. They can't work correctly with 802.1X which is a *port authentication* protocol **on the network edge**.  Likely, those switches authenticate their entire uplink which completely defies the intention of port authentication.

802.1X doesn't and can't authenticate end nodes (unless augmented by MAC authentication which is only a marginal improvement due to the inherent impossibility to rely on MAC addresses).

For 802.1X to work correctly, *managed* switches as authenticators are required for the client ports. Obviously, you need to connect the clients to the managed switch ports directly, with no intermediate hub or switch - which you need to actively prevent. You need to set up those ports to disallow multiple clients in order to make 802.1X halfway secure.

Likely, the only thing those unmanaged switches differ in is their behavior of passing through 802.1X authentication frames - which the v3 appears to do and the v2 doesn't. The effect of that pass-through is that the first client on the GS608v3 authenticates the upstream switch's port and all other clients are free to join. That is probably not what you want.

802.1X isn't very secure to start with. Unless combined with additional measures it's hardly worth the trouble - a half-wit can circumvent basic authentication in moments. If you need decent port-level access security MACsec is the only standard choice.

Comment: Thats the thing, 802.1x  is working correctly with GS608v3 and Up (v4) unmanaged switches but not with GS608v2. something was was introduced in v3 and up that allows those unmanaged switches to work with 802.1x correctly.

Comment: The v3 is *not* working correctly - an unmanaged switch simply can't. A client port needs to be authenticated *on the switch the client connects to*, not the next best upstream switch.

Comment: what do you mean by "v3 is not working correctly"? I am connecting 3 different machines on the the GS608v3 Switch that are getting full access to the network and are authenticating correctly based on the logs from the back end, I see that the authentication is succesful with my username per each MAC address.

Comment: Apparently, you're not authenticating the ports but the MAC addresses. You know how easily those can be spoofed, do you? The 802.1X protocol is often modified to authenticate MAC addresses but strictly speaking, that isn't 802.1X. Also, the security level is much lower (which isn't very good to start with anyway).

Comment: I never said that MAC address is used to authenticate, I'm saying that I am using the  MAC address to identify the device sitting on the port, I see the endpoints authenticating when connecting to the 802.1x enabled port. To answer your question, Yes I am aware that a MAC address can be easily spoofed (you dont have to sound condescending), besides, that is completely not what i was asking, the question is what is different in a GS608v2 switch vs v3.

Comment: I've added some details to the answer to get the point across. The thing is that your 802.1X setup is most likely flawed.

Comment: ok, Thank you for clarifying the part about 802.1x. My question is why does this setup work with a GS608v3 Switch and not v3.